# How to change the default jsp directory that my Spring Mvc application is using?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I have created a simple spring mvc application using IntelliJ Idea 12 IDE, and I want to find a way to change the default folder that the applications is using for storing jsp pages (WEB-INF/pages) to WEB-INF/views.
I even tried to delete the pages directory but after deploying the application it tries again to find my jsp file inside the WEB-INF/pages.
Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That was too easy...but it seems that when you are tired you can ask easy questions.
I just changed this setting in my default servlet config file :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jspx"/>
</bean>
```