# How to change default JSP/template location with Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, configuration, struts2

I'm working on a new Java EE application that uses Struts2 in Eclipse. I want to keep the JSP files in the source folder (`src/main/jsp`) and not in `WebContent`. When deployed, the all source files get copied over to `WebContent/WEB-INF/classes`. This also has the bonus effect of making the jsp files inaccessible directly (I want everything to require action intervention). This means that to make results display, I have to do this:

```xml
<result name="SUCCESS">WEB-INF/classes/index.jsp</result>
```

Is it possible to set the default location of the jsp files so that just `index.jsp` is sufficient to reference them? Ideally the files would also sit in `WEB-INF/jsp` and not get mixed with the classes.

I saw that [spring has this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264211/how-to-change-the-default-jsp-directory-that-my-spring-mvc-application-is-using). I'm hoping for the same thing for Struts2.

Comment: If you are using the Convention plugin, take a look at the [Result Path configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28381238/1654265). If you are not using the Convention plugin, start using the Convention plugin :)

Comment: Trying to make it work, I'll get back to you with the results when it works/I give up.

Comment: Looks like it requires usage of annotations which is a no go, unfortunately. I guess I'll just stick to repetitive paths.

Comment: Are you using maven? Put your jsp-s into `webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/` in that way there are not mixed with classes. As for the path take a look at tiles.

Comment: I'd love to use maven, but workplace enforces ant only. But in any case, I want the jsp files in the `src` folder.

Comment: In maven `webapp` folder is in the `src` -> `src/main/webapp`.

Comment: Why do you put jsp-s in src if you don't use maven? You can copy them into desired place when you are building war.

Comment: Because jsp files are also source files. But that's unrelated as even putting them directly into `WEB-INF/pages` still requires me to put the full path which is the original issue.

Comment: I don't think there's a config option for the root of JSP files, regardless where they live in the pre-packaged project. You could modify the default result types to allow this, which should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a constant configuration parameter, e.g.

```xml
<constant name="struts.result.path" value="/WEB-INF/classes" />
```

Then inject this constant into custom `dispatcher` result. Add this to your default package:

```xml
<result-types>
    <result-type name="dispatcher" default="true" class="struts.results.MyServletDispatcherResult" />
</result-types>
```

The implementation is easy, you just add a prefix to the location of the result when it's configured.

```java
public class MyServletDispatcherResult extends ServletDispatcherResult {

    private String resultPath;

    public String getResultPath() {
        return resultPath;
    }

    @Inject(value = "struts.result.path", required = false)
    public void setResultPath(String resultPath) {
        this.resultPath = resultPath;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        super.setLocation(resultPath+location);
    }

    public MyServletDispatcherResult() {
        super();
    }

//    @Inject
//    public MyServletDispatcherResult(String location) {
//
//        super(resultPath+location);
//    }
}
```

Then you can use ordinary locations in the results, e.g.

```xml
<result name="SUCCESS">/index.jsp</result>
```

Comment: Sounds like it would work. I'll try it tomorrow at work.

Comment: Yup, it worked. Had to create a custom base package that all other packages extend so I only have to declare the custom dispatcher once.